# Java Webdriver HashMap element array

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
String name = "";
    String width = "";
    String height = "";



    List<WebElement> imageName = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.card-arago div.hover-info div.name"));
    List<HashMap> imageInfo = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    imageInfo.add(attributes);
    for (WebElement image : imageName) {
        attributes.put("name",image.getText());
    }
    List<WebElement> images = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.card-arago a img"));
    for (WebElement image : images) {
        attributes.put("width", image.getAttribute("width"));
        attributes.put("height", image.getAttribute("height"));

    }
```

I'm trying to return all the images from the page, but it only returns the last image card on the page?

Answer (score 1):

A HashMap can only store one value with each key.  If you call `put` with the same key more than once, each call overwrites the previous.  You are calling `attributes.put("name", ...)` multiple times in a loop, so the value attached to the key "name" gets replaced over and over again, and at the end of the loop is just left with the last image.  If you actually want all images to be returned, you either need unique keys for each image, or an entirely separate HashMap for each image, depending on how you want to structure this.

EDIT: after looking at your code a bit more, it looks like you do want a List of HashMaps. But you only ever add one single HashMap to that List. Instead, you could change that first loop to add a new HashMap for each image.

Comment: That sounds like that would be the easiest way. How would have it add a new HashMap for each image?

Answer (score 0):

When calling put(k,v);, the key is stored and the value is the extra metadata. Just a key and a value.
If I call put(1, 2); and then call put(1, 3); the value returned by get(1); will be 3. the put(k,v); function only stores different objects within the HashMap. You can not have the same values within the same HashMap, however, you can have the same values within the same HashMap.

To solve your problem, I suggest you use an identifier such like

```
attributes.put("width" + someIntIdentifier, image.getAttribute("width");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a map and keep updating the key values , for one key a map can have  only one value (it replaces the previous value). Alternatively you may try using a List of map, which will contain your map containing info about image.

```
String name = "";
String width = "";
String height = "";


List imageNameList = new ArrayList(); // creating list to store imageName
List imageAttributesList = new ArrayList(); // creating list to store image height and width


List<WebElement> imageName = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.card-arago div.hover-info div.name"));
List<HashMap> imageInfo = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
imageInfo.add(attributes);
for (WebElement image : imageName) {
    HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    attributes.put("name",image.getText());

    imageNameList.add(attributes); // adding map to list
}
List<WebElement> images = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.card-arago a img"));
for (WebElement image : images) {

    HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();

    attributes.put("width", image.getAttribute("width"));
    attributes.put("height", image.getAttribute("height"));

    imageAttributesList.add(attributes); // adding map to list
}


System.out.println(imageNameList); // this will give you a list of Map having "name" key
System.out.println(imageAttributesList); // this will give you a list of Map having "height" and "width" of image
```

Here I have created two List to store image name and height & width . Like this you can get attributes of all the images you needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're attempting to do, I agree with jthomas about returning a list of HashMaps. Additionally, rather than managing and looping a list of elements with the name text and then separately finding and looping the dimensions of the image element, you should be able to consolidate a bit if, I assume, both of those elements are within a common div. I would do something like this:

```
List<HashMap> images = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
List<WebElement> imageDivs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.card-arago");

for (WebElement imageDiv : imageDivs) {
    HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    attributes.put("name", imageDiv.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.name").getText();

    WebElement image = imageDiv.findElement(By.tagName("img");
    attributes.put("width", image.getAttribute("width"));
    attributes.put("height", image.getAttribute("height"));
    images.add(attributes);
}
```

The images list would then give you a hashmap for each image card on the page, each of which contained the name, height, and width of that image. Then you could iterate that list as you please.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Multimap which stores multiple values for single key.
https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html